# Vaciar un formulario luego de enviar los datos - HTML Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

tengo un formulario que al enviarlo realiza la validación del mismo.

Esto hace que los inputs, en caso de error, vuelvan a cargar los valores ingresados y que hayan sido válidos, y solo limpia aquellos que hayan sido erroneos. (esto es lo planeado)

Ahora tengo dificultades al limpiar ese formulario, por que el reset no los limpia, o mejor dicho, no los deja vacios.

```html
<body>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cajas.css">
  <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#inputProduccion").datepicker({
    closeText: 'Cerrar',
    prevText: '<Ant',
    nextText: 'Sig>',
    currentText: 'Hoy',
    monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
    dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mié', 'Juv', 'Vie', 'Sáb'],
    dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sá'],
    weekHeader: 'Sm',
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    firstDay: 1,
    isRTL: false,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    yearSuffix: '',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
  }) /*.datepicker("setDate", new Date())*/ ;
});

  </script>



  <div class="banner">
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h1>Ingreso de Datos</h1>
    <hr>
    <form method="POST" novalidate="">
      <div class="form-group is-invalid">
        <label for="inputRutEmpresa" class="float-left">Rut Empresa</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" id="inputRutEmpresa" name="rutEmpresa" placeholder="Rut de Empresa" value="123456789" required="">
        <div class="invalid-feedback float-left">
          Ingrese un rut válido por favor </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputNombreRazon" class="float-left">Nombre / Razon Social</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" id="inputNombreRazon" name="razonSocial" placeholder="Nombre o Razon Social" value="qwerty" required="">
        <div class="invalid-feedback float-left">
          Ingrese Nombre o Razón Social </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputRutRepresentante" class="float-left">Rut Representante</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" id="inputRutRepresentante" name="rutRep" placeholder="Rut Representante" value="" required="">
            <!--div erroneo-->
          <div class="invalid-feedback float-left">
            Ingrese un rut válido por favor </div>
        </div> <!--div trasladado-->
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputRepresentante" class="float-left">Nombre Representante</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" id="inputRepresentante" name="nomRep" placeholder="Nombre Representante" value="" required="">
          <!--div erroneo-->
          <div class="invalid-feedback float-left">
            Ingrese Nombre de Representante </div>
        </div> <!--div trasladado-->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputDistribuidor" class="float-left">Distribuidor</label>
        <select name="distribuidor" class="custom-select" required="">
          <option value="">Seleccione Distribuidor...</option>
          <option selected value="1">ONE</option>
          <option value="2">Gerson</option>
          <option value="3">NGR</option>
          <option value="4">Otro</option>
        </select>
        <div class="invalid-feedback float-left">
          Seleccione un Distribuidor </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputSucursal" class="float-left">Sucursal</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control is-invalid" id="inputSucursal" name="sucursal" required="">
          <div class="invalid-feedback float-left">
            Seleccione un Sucursal </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEquipo" class="float-left">Equipo</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputEquipo" value="1" required="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputCaja" class="float-left">ID Caja</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCaja" value="1" required="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputServidor" class="float-left">Servidor</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputServidor" value="1" required="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ingresar</button>
      <input type="reset" class="btn btn-warning" value="Limpiar" onclick="$('.is-invalid').removeClass('is-invalid');">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
  <div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remuevelo usando las siguientes líneaa en el botón limpiar:

```
// Remueve la clase 'is-invalid'
$('.is-invalid').removeClass('is-invalid');

// Remueve el valor de todos los inputs excepto los que se listan
$(':input').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden,:radio,:checkbox, option').removeAttr('value');

// Deselecciona todos los radios, los checkboxs y las opciones.
$('option,:radio,:checkbox').removeAttr('selected').removeAttr('checked');
```

Basicamente seleccionas tu todos los inputs y eliminas sus valores. Debes hacerlo manualmente de esta manera ya que el reset de jquery lo resetea pero al estado inicial, es decir, con los valores con que fue cargado el formulario. No borra los valores con los que lo mandaste.

```html
<body>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cajas.css">
  <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#inputProduccion").datepicker({
    closeText: 'Cerrar',
    prevText: '<Ant',
    nextText: 'Sig>',
    currentText: 'Hoy',
    monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
    dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mié', 'Juv', 'Vie', 'Sáb'],
    dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sá'],
    weekHeader: 'Sm',
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    firstDay: 1,
    isRTL: false,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    yearSuffix: '',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
  }) /*.datepicker("setDate", new Date())*/ ;
});

  </script>



  <div class="banner">
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h1>Ingreso de Datos</h1>
    <hr>
    <form method="POST" novalidate="">
      <div class="form-group is-invalid">
        <label for="inputRutEmpresa" class="float-left">Rut Empresa</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" id="inputRutEmpresa" name="rutEmpresa" placeholder="Rut de Empresa" value="123456789" required="">
        <div class="invalid-feedback float-left">
          Ingrese un rut válido por favor </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputNombreRazon" class="float-left">Nombre / Razon Social</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" id="inputNombreRazon" name="razonSocial" placeholder="Nombre o Razon Social" value="qwerty" required="">
        <div class="invalid-feedback float-left">
          Ingrese Nombre o Razón Social </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputRutRepresentante" class="float-left">Rut Representante</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" id="inputRutRepresentante" name="rutRep" placeholder="Rut Representante" value="" required="">
            <!--div erroneo-->
          <div class="invalid-feedback float-left">
            Ingrese un rut válido por favor </div>
        </div> <!--div trasladado-->
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputRepresentante" class="float-left">Nombre Representante</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" id="inputRepresentante" name="nomRep" placeholder="Nombre Representante" value="" required="">
          <!--div erroneo-->
          <div class="invalid-feedback float-left">
            Ingrese Nombre de Representante </div>
        </div> <!--div trasladado-->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputDistribuidor" class="float-left">Distribuidor</label>
        <select name="distribuidor" class="custom-select" required="">
          <option value="">Seleccione Distribuidor...</option>
          <option selected value="1">ONE</option>
          <option value="2">Gerson</option>
          <option value="3">NGR</option>
          <option value="4">Otro</option>
        </select>
        <div class="invalid-feedback float-left">
          Seleccione un Distribuidor </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputSucursal" class="float-left">Sucursal</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control is-invalid" id="inputSucursal" name="sucursal" required="">
          <div class="invalid-feedback float-left">
            Seleccione un Sucursal </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEquipo" class="float-left">Equipo</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputEquipo" value="1" required="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputCaja" class="float-left">ID Caja</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCaja" value="1" required="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputServidor" class="float-left">Servidor</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputServidor" value="1" required="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ingresar</button>
      <input type="reset" class="btn btn-warning" value="Limpiar" onclick="$('.is-invalid').removeClass('is-invalid');$(':input').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden,:radio,:checkbox,option').removeAttr('value');$('option,:radio,:checkbox').removeAttr('selected').removeAttr('checked');">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
  <div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Y se puede agregar que el SELECT quede en la primera seleccion igual?

Comment: Listo, solo era agregar `$('option').removeAttr('selected')`

Comment: Gracias quedo espectacular !! ;) Algun dia entenderé mejor jquery XD

Comment: Me alegra te haya servido, igual comenté y separé cada línea para que quede mas clara la magia XD. Saludos.